# Dropdown was hiding. opacity, overflow and z-index not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

[image]

Dropdown is hiding. I dont know what problem. If i give opacity and overflow visible it is not working. I have tried in inspect element, but it is not working.

Code for text box:-

```
<input class="typeahead form-control tt-input" id="search" placeholder="Location" type="text" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" aria-activedescendant="" aria-owns="search_listbox" role="combobox" aria-readonly="true" aria-autocomplete="list" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;">
```

CSS:-

```
element.style {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.form-control {
    padding: 10px 22px;
    border: 4px solid #938F94;
    height: 47px;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Code for tt-menu:-(Dropdown)

```
element.style {
    position: initial;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}
.tt-menu {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

How to make it overflow visible?

Comment: Maybe your parent div has a x height and 'overflow hidden" (?) Post your code.

Comment: @user5195185 , there is no hight for parent div , it is auto height.

Comment: @Logeshwaran You can try by giving property to parent element as :   overflow: visible;

Comment: Share the code from the css file (not from the browser inspector).

Answer (score 0):

use this code if you are using bootstrap dropdown.

```
.dropdown{
   z-index:9999;
}
```